# Design of MAC unit using VHDL - error "Array sizes do not match"

Tags: vhdl

Trying to design a simple MAC Unit in VHDL

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


entity MAC is
  port (
    DIN:        IN  signed(15 downto 0);
    WEIGHT:     IN  signed(15 downto 0);
    CLK:        IN  std_logic;
    RST:        IN  std_logic;
    RESULT:     OUT signed(15 downto 0);
  );
end entity MAC;

architecture base of MAC is
begin

  process(CLK)
  variable acc_value : signed(15 downto 0);

  begin
   IF rising_edge(CLK) then
        
      IF RST='1' THEN
        acc_value := (OTHERS => '0'); -- reset accumulated value to 0
      ELSE
        acc_value := (acc_value + WEIGHT* DIN);
        RESULT <= acc_value;
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END process; 
end base;
```

Seems like there is a problem with  `acc_value := (acc_value + WEIGHT* DIN);` .
There is an error in the simulation **"ERROR: Array sizes do not match, left array has 16 elements, right array has 32 elements"** with confuses me, because for me both arrays have 16 bits (or?)

Comment: The addition operator has two operands, acc_value has a length of 16. the other operand is the expression WEIGHT * DIN which has a length the sum of the multiply operator operands length which is 32 (See package numeric_std, the operator overload implementing function "*" [signed, signed return signed].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of overflowing, you need to take care of that.

`acc_value := (acc_value + WEIGHT* DIN);`

In the right hand side, `WEIGHT * DIN` is 16 bit * 16 bit = 32 bits. Adding the 16-bit `acc_value` to that (`acc_value + WEIGHT*DIN`) gives you a 32-bit value, which cannot be assigned into the 16-bit variable signed `acc_value`.